# How do alternating Christmas tree lights work?

Tags: led

I saw these alternating Christmas lights:

[image: Christmas lights with all lights on]

[image: Christmas lights with odd-numbered lights on][image: Christmas lights with even-numbered lights on]

The top image has all lights on, the bottom left image has odd-numbered lights on, and the bottom right image has even-numbered lights on.

The LEDS are joined by two enameled wires, and three AA batteries power the lot.

How does the controller turn the odd-numbered lights on and off?

Answer (score 5):

These kinds of lights have LEDs connected in an alternating polarity fashion. Take look at the following circuit.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fEyCLY.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Lights with this kind of configuration are cheaper to make and adequately serve their purpose.

The controller is able to power the LEDs in the following two ways to create the effect:

1. P1 (HIGH), P2 (LOW)... all even LEDs are on.
2. P1 (LOW), P2 (HIGH)... all odd LEDs are on.
3. AC ... all LEDs on (actually just alternating too fast to see)

Comment: Actually, it's probably AC all the time, and the controller just plays with the duty cycle in order to create a cross-fade effect.

Comment: Cheaper to make than what?

Comment: @Misunderstood, cheaper than using something like addressable leds for the same effect.

Comment: I got hold of the lights and the power supply plugs directly to the power outlet. The sign says "U_rated=4.5V~ U_out=4.5V~" and "Combination in waves: sequential, slo-glo, chasing/flash, slow fade, twinkle/flash, steady on." I hooked a multimeter on AC voltage and I measure between 0 and 2 volts most of the time, except some 0 voltage at some points when the lights are on, so I assume those have DC.

Comment: @DaveTweed How can I test your explanation with a multimeter?

Comment: No easy way I can think of. But it would be trivial with an oscilloscope. Can you get your hands on one?